# Excel VBA: Advanced rearranging data in new table for export

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, csv, export

you are my last resort :)
I have been struggling with the following Excel VBA job:

Out of a huge XLS with product data of which I need to export some of the data in a special rearrange format: Variations of the same product must be exported as an addition to the base product instead of being a seperate product.

The rearranged data has to be exported to a .CSV text file in order to be able to be imported into Adobe Indesign (for a data merge).

The images will explain the process even better: See the links below.

The source file looks something like this:***Base Table***

[image]

It contains one column "CatStyleNr" that serves as a check to see if a product is to be of other parts. During the export, products with the same "CatStyleNr" should be combined in one row, instead of different rows.

The necessary result looks like: ***Export Table***

[image]

The solutions, as far as I can think of, is to run through every row of the Base Table and to check if the value in cell "CatStyleNr" already exists in the Export Table (on a second worksheet or invisible?). If it doesn't exist yet, a new row should be added and the data should be copied. if the "CatStyleNr" already exists, it should be added to the existing row...

If have been trying different macro's based on short parts I could copy from other threads but it just doesn't work out.

Anyone who can help me? Thank you in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have so far:

Sub ExportTXT()

Dim i As Variant 'row source

With Worksheets("SELECTION").PivotTables("Selection")
For i = 1 To 100
If Worksheets("EXPORT").ListObjects("TableExport").ListColumns("CatStyleNr").DataBodyRange(i) = .PivotFields("CatStyleNr").PivotItems(i) Then
    Worksheets("EXPORT").ListObjects("TableExport").ListColumns("Height2").DataBodyRange(i) = .PivotFields("Height").PivotItems(i)
Else
    Worksheets("EXPORT").ListObjects("TableExport").ListColumns("Name").DataBodyRange(i) = .PivotFields("Name").PivotItems(i)

End If
Next i
End With

End Sub

But it always got stuck...